# Is there a concept of meta-transactions in Substrate?

Tags: substrate

I want to know if there's a concept similar to Meta-transactions in Substrate.
"A meta transaction is a regular Ethereum transaction which contains another transaction, the actual transaction. The actual transaction is signed by a user and then sent to an operator or something similar, no gas and blockchain interaction required. The operator takes this signed transaction and submits it to the blockchain paying for the fees himself." [2](http://%20https://soliditydeveloper.com/meta-transactions)
You can learn further about meta-transactions in Ethereum from these articles:
[Ethereum Meta-Transactions 101](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-meta-transactions-101-de7f91884a06)
[How to implement generalized Meta-transactions?](http://%20https://soliditydeveloper.com/meta-transactions)

I want to implement a substrate pallet where I can airdrop certain amount of tokens native to the substrate blockchain and let users with 0 balance claim  according to their interaction with some other protocols built on other blockchains.

I researched some feeless mechanisms in Substrate and built a feeless pallet inspired from tutorials by Shawn tabrizi so that my pallet could send balance to users for a certain transaction. But I don't see how I can best implement this mechanism without risking a sybil attack on the blockchain. In ethereum, due to the concept of meta-transactions, it's pretty easy to onboard new users to a certain protocol. What's a possible equivalent case in Substrate for onboarding non-substrate users to a new substrate blockchain?